# Restful web service Json fields starting with capital names

Tags: json

I build a restfulwebservice using Jackson & gson  parsing in eclipse.

My code is working fine if my starting letter of my input Json text is small i.e

```
{
  "fields":"value"

}
```

it is returning a response message  like

```
{
  "fields":"value"

}
```

but if my json text starts with a capital i.e

```
{

  "Ord_Num":"value"
}
```

it is returning {} i.e null. (I used @JsonProperty("Ord_Num") String ordnum)

Please find my gson parser and input parser file below.

```
@Path("/hello")
public class Hello {
@GET
@Path("/response")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public static Response getSampleResponse() {
    return Response.status(200).build();
}

@POST
@Path("/send")
public static Response postSampleResponse(SamplePojo sp) {

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    gson.toJson(sp);
    return Response.status(201).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .entity(gson.toJson(sp)).build();

}
}
```

Sampplepojo.java:

```
public class SamplePojo {

@JsonProperty("Ord_Num") String ordnum;

public String getOrdnum() {
    return ordnum;
}

public void setOrdnum(String field) {
    this.ordnum = field;

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The JSON standard says:

> The literal names MUST be lowercase.  No other literal names are allowed.

That's why you get an empty JSON object if you try to use capital letters.

See the RFC for JSON: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627

Comment: Is there any work around as my end client is sending the Json file with capitals

Comment: Since it is no valid json you are not able to use gson or other json frameworks. But you can parse the json by yourself!

Comment: Zeldon Can you provide an example showing how to parse the incorrect Json file as described above

Comment: is this valid JSON isDeleted as I noticed Jackson parse it as deleted ? any one